# Build doesn't finish when I add a localized resource file

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, localization, windows-10

We recently upgraded everyone to windows 10.  Everyone on my team who upgraded to Win10 can build the C# solution we have in TFS, but I am the only person who did a clean install of Win10 and can't do a build.  I will add that I had been able to build this project last week on Windows 10 in VS2015 without issue but can't remember if I had done a rebuild or clean solution for this project's DLLs.

When I say I can't build, the build process starts and then just sits at 50% until I cancel the build.  There are no errors in the output window that would hint at what the issue is.  I have the same problem in both VS2013 and VS2015 and in all branches so I can rule out code changes.

I have removed all files from the project until I determined that it was a Resources.ja-JP.resx resource that was causing the issue.  Excluding this one file from the project allows the project to build in a matter of seconds.

I have tested adding an empty resource file, add item --> Resource file --> "Resources.de-DE.resx" just like the instructions in this [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa992030%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). I have also tried with another language Resources.ja-JP.resx and get the same issue.

My suspicion is that there is some environment issue on my machine that is preventing VS2015 from creating the localized resource dlls.

Does anyone have a solution to address or ideas to check to determine the issue.